# Why does the / directory have .. and what does it mean?

Tags: directory

While in the `/` directory and use `ls -a`  the result will contain `.` and `..`

I can understand the existence of the `.` that is a pointer for the directory itself. What it is the meaning of having the `..` in the `/` directory while there is no parent directory for the `/`?

Comment: The topic is discussed here: http://superuser.com/questions/186184/the-parent-of-the-root-directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many softwares work on the assumptions, *not* in fact guaranteed to them by POSIX.1 but traditionally the case on UNIX systems and enshrined in much UNIX literature, that (to quote one such piece of UNIX literature):

> Every directory contains the file names dot and dot-dot (`.` and `..`) whose inode numbers are those of the directory and its parent directory, respectively. *[…]* The program `mkfs` initializes a filesystem so that `.` and `..` of the root directory have the root inode number of the file system.

— Maurice J. Bach (1986). *The Design of the UNIX Operating System.*  Prentice Hall. p. 73

For example: The old `getcwd()` library function (on systems that provided no special kernel support for it) relies upon this to *know when to stop* tracing up the chain of `..` entries when composing the current directory name.  It stops when it reaches a directory that is its own parent, or cannot traverse to `..`.

So the reason that the root directory has (or as far as applications-mode programs are concerned at least *appears* to have as seen through the system API) a `..` entry is that a lot of stuff is based upon the assumption that *every* directory has `..`, and that `..` in the root being a loop can be used for detecting that one is at the root.

POSIX.1 does not in fact guarantee that the root directory has a `..`, merely specifying that *programs have to account for the possibility of a loop if* there is a `..` in the root directory.  This is to permit non-UNIX systems to be POSIX-conformant too.  There are file systems where the *absence* of `..` indicates that a directory is a root directory.  And there are, as Bach himself discusses, systems where there is a directory *above* the root, which POSIX.1 allows for in its discussion of absolute pathnames that begin with *two* slashes (similar to the Universal Naming Convention used in Microsoft local area network systems).

Linux (and thus Ubuntu Linux), however, provides the stricter guarantees of the UNIX paradigm.

Answer (score -1):

Very simply:
by means of file directory, `./` means ***this folder***, while `../` means ***where the file is*** (e.g when I'm in the directory `user/home/me/Desktop`, then `../` will bring me to `/user/home/me`).

Comment: Ok. How does this answer the question, that `/` has no parent directory for `/../` to point to?

Comment: Now that your question is well edited, I understand what you actually asked ;)<br>
About that, the answer of JdeBP explains well.